# Can't receive message in Socket.io room with Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to create a room with socket.io for a chat on my website.

Unfortunately, even if the messages are sent correctly and both users have joined the same room the messages are not received..

Here is my code so far:

`chat.component.ts`:

```
// both users joining the same room with their matchId
// __________________________________________________________________

joinRoom(matchId) {
  try {
    this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    this.socket.emit('join room', matchId.toString());
  } catch (e) {
   console.log('Could not connect socket.io');
  }
}


// emiting the message object
// __________________________________________________________________

this.socket.emit('send message', obj);


// receiving the message object and pushing it to the messageList
// __________________________________________________________________

receive = (obj) => {
  if (obj) {
    this.messageList.push(obj);
  }
}

ngOnInit() {
  try {
    this.socket.on('receive message', this.receive);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Could not connect socket.io');
  }
}
```

`backend`:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var roomId;
  socket.on('join room', function(room) {
    socket.join(room);
    console.log('a user connected to room', room);
    roomId = room;
  });
  socket.on('send message', (obj) => {
    socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit('receive message', obj);
  });
});
```

I am receiving both `join room` and `send message` events..

What can I do to receive the messages in the room?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you receiving the 'join room' event? I would assume you are not, but just to be sure.

Comment: @TimVN Absolutely, the message object is received too

Comment: I see. The one thing I can imagine is that you are not actually waiting for the socket to connect before joining the room. ```this.socket``` will emit a ```connection``` event, maybe try joining the room when that event fires.
edit: I'm misreading what you're doing here, sorry, I will take another look.

Comment: are you spinning the server on several threads?

Comment: @TimVN I tried moving the `io.connect('http://localhost:3000')` line into the `ngOnInit` to be sure that the socket is connected before firing `joinRoom()` without success..

Comment: @cnps well it used to work before using rooms, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Are you for example using workers to spawn multiple instances of your server.

Comment: @cnps hum no, should I?

Comment: Have you tried ```io.to``` instead of ```socket.broadcast.to```?

Comment: @TimVN it works! Unfornately every room can receive the messages from other rooms, is `this.socket.on('receive message', this.receive);` correct?

Comment: @cnps not necessarily, but it could be the reason.

Comment: Only sockets subscribed to that room will receive messages you broadcast to it, the way you're listening for messages there is fine.

Comment: @TimVN Oh I see, I guess this is happening because I am not leaving the room when entering another one